# Change the default settings for tsconfig.json that get created with "tsc --init"?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if there was a way to change the default settings for the tsconfig.json file that gets created by tsc --init?

Answer (score 6):

To make changes in the default `tsconfig.json` file, use compiler options while initialization. Example:

> .\node_modules.bin\tsc --init --allowJs true

It generates a tsconfig.json file and also overrides the default property of `allowJs` from `false` to `true`.

Comment: @brian-le If this answers your query, kindly consider accepting my ans.